# Strange Performance Issues with INNER JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I was using a query that looked similar to this one:

```
SELECT `episodes`.*, IFNULL(SUM(`views_sum`.`clicks`), 0) as `clicks`
FROM `episodes`, `views_sum`
WHERE `views_sum`.`index` = "episode" AND `views_sum`.`key` = `episodes`.`id`
GROUP BY `episodes`.`id`
```

... which takes ~0.1s to execute.  But it's problematic, because some `episodes` don't have a corresponding `views_sum` row, so those episodes aren't included in the result.

What I want is NULL values when a corresponding `views_sum` row doesn't exist, so I tried using a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
SELECT `episodes`.*, IFNULL(SUM(`views_sum`.`clicks`), 0) as `clicks`
FROM `episodes`
LEFT JOIN `views_sum` ON (`views_sum`.`index` = "episode" AND `views_sum`.`key` = `episodes`.`id`)
GROUP BY `episodes`.`id`
```

This query produces the same columns, and it also includes the few rows missing from the 1st query.

*BUT*, the 2nd query takes 10 times as long!  A full second.

Why is there such a huge discrepancy between the execution times when the result is so similar?  There's nowhere *near* 10 times as many rows — it's like 60 from the 1st query, and 70 from the 2nd.  That's not to mention that the 10 additional rows have no `views` to sum!

Any light shed would be greatly appreciated!

(There are indexes on `episodes.id`, `views_sum.index`, and `views_sum.key`.)

**EDIT:**

I copy-pasted the SQL from above, and here are the EXPLAINs, in order:

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref                         rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      views_sum   ref     index,key       index       27          const                       6532    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      episodes    eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4           db102914_itw.views_sum.key  1       Using where

id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref                         rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      episodes    ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL                        70      Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      views_sum   ref     index,key       index       27          const                       6532
```

Comment: I corrected your title, because there's no cross join in either example.  A cross join produces a cartesian product, but the first query uses ANSI-89 inner join syntax.

Comment: Thanks, OMG. So a CROSS JOIN is an INNER JOIN without any comparison between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the query I ultimately came up with, after many, many iterations.  (The `SQL_NO_CACHE` flag is there so I can test execution times.)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE e.*, IFNULL(SUM(vs.`clicks`), 0) as `clicks`

FROM `episodes` e

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM `views_sum` WHERE `index` = "episode") vs
ON vs.`key` = e.`id`

GROUP BY e.`id`
```

Because the ON condtion `views_sum.index = "episode"` is static, i.e., isn't dependent on the row it's joined to, I was able to get a massive performance boost by first using a subquery to limit the `views_sum` table *before* joining.

My query now takes ~0.2s.  And what's even better, the time doesn't grow as you increase the offset of the query (unlike my first LEFT JOIN attempt).  It stays the same, even if you do a sort on the `clicks` column.

Comment: Well done. An unrelated hint: you don't have to always use table aliases. Sometimes they improve the readability of the query; sometimes they don't. Here, I don't think they do.

Comment: You're right, I'd prefer to not use aliases, but I need to use one for the filtered `views_sum` table.  Otherwise, I get the error: "Every derived table must have its own alias" (which makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a *combined* index on `views_sum`.`index` and `views_sum`.`key`. I suspect you will always use both fields together if i look at the names. Also, I would rewrite the first query to use a proper INNER JOIN clause instead of a filtered cartesian product.

I suspect the performance of both queries will be much closer together if you do this. And, more importantly, much faster than they are now.

edit: Thinking about it, I would probably add a third column to that index: `views_sum`.`clicks`, which probably can be used for the SUM. But remember that multi-column indexes can only be used left to right.

Comment: I didn't even know you could make a combined index... I came up with another answer, but I'll go try this, too (would be simpler than the subquery method, anyway).

Comment: mySQL can't use more than 1 index per table in a query. So combined indexes are very important in getting optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the indexes.  You'll have to play around with it a bit or post your database schema on here.  Just as a rough guess i'd say you should make sure you have an index on views_sum.key.

Comment: Check the very end of my question.  Thanks for the thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a `LEFT JOIN` will be slower than an `INNER JOIN` or a `CROSS JOIN` because it has to view the first table differently. Put another way, the difference in time isn't related to the size of the *result*, but the *full size of the left table*.

I also wonder if you're asking MySQL to figure things out for you that you should be doing yourself. Specifically, that `SUM()` function would normally require a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include `GROUP BY episode.id`, sorry!

Comment: One thing I would try is to shift the `views_sum.index = "episode"` clause out to a `WHERE`, but you would also get more information putting the whole query through an `EXPLAIN`, too.